# Deploy Laravel with Dokku

Tags: laravel, dokku

I can not understand how correctly to deploy it.

What I want to do?

1. All my Laravel project should be in bitbucket (Also in here is Dockerfile for local deploy);
2. When I deploy with dokku it should deploy my Laravel project from bitbucket and run Laravel app commands: migrate, seed, and so on.

What is right now happening?

1. Dokku builds my Laravel app from bitbucket and loads Docerfile. So I added to Dockerfile something like this in the end:

```
COPY docker/id_docker /home/docker/.ssh/id_rsa
COPY docker/id_docker.pub /home/docker/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
COPY docker/known_hosts /home/docker/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN eval "$(ssh-agent)" && ssh-agent -s
RUN if [ "$BUILD_ENV" = "production" ] ; then cd $APP_HOME && git clone         git@bitbucket.org:laravel.git; fi
RUN if [ "$BUILD_ENV" = "production" ] ; then cd $APP_HOME/laravel && composer install; fi
RUN if [ "$BUILD_ENV" = "production" ] ; then cd $APP_HOME/laravel && cp .env.example .env; fi
RUN if [ "$BUILD_ENV" = "production" ] ; then cd $APP_HOME/laravel && php artisan key:generate; fi
```

But I know it should not to be like this;D

So I need some help how can I deploy it? I should use Jenkins or maybe exists dokku files something like Pecilfile or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what I decided:

1. First of all it is app.json file. When build finishing build from Dockerfile its runs predeploy and postdeploy.

   `{
     "name": "laravel",
     "description": "laravel app on Dokku/Heroku.",
     "keywords": [
       "laravel",
       "dokku",
       "heroku"
     ],
     "scripts": {
       "dokku": {
         "predeploy": "dokku/predeploy.sh",
         "postdeploy": "dokku/postdeploy.sh"
       }
     }
   }`

dokku folder is in project root directory.

!!!!!IMPORTANT!!!!!!  - Something is wrong then in predeploy.sh when running composer install. Laravel maybe change something in server or bad .env file. So it build from Dockerfile and installs composer deps. Then dokku waiting 10sec to check if container is ok, but it fails some how and do not prints error. ;/

2. Next what I did. Created Dockerfile with main image for laravel;
3. Created init.sh for dokku to run php artisan migrate, seed, .env and so one;
4. Created rebuild.sh to rebuild dokku image and do something what need be done every build;

So if you know what can be wrong for app.json predeploy, please write in comments :)

**---- EDIT 2018-10-20 ----**

Right now I has good news. Finally I know what is wrong. By default dokku has ENTRYPOINT to init.sh and this file in my docker project not exists. So its important to specify ENTRYPOINT to Dockerfile. In my case it is:

`ENTRYPOINT [""]
    CMD ["dumb-init", "php", "src/tokara-auto-laravel/artisan", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]`

And do not forget create app.json file. If you specify in Dockerfile not default WORKDIR so you can write something ike this in your Dockerfile:

`WORKDIR /home/docker
    COPY app.json /home/docker
    COPY dokku /home/docker/dokku`

And my app.json:

`{
      "name": "laravel",
      "description": Llaravel app on Dokku/Heroku.",
      "keywords": [
            "laravel",
            "dokku",
            "heroku"
      ],
      "scripts": {
            "dokku": {
                  "predeploy": "/home/docker/dokku/predeploy.sh",
                  "postdeploy": "/home/docker/dokku/postdeploy.sh"
            }
      }
    }`